# Where are repos located

Tags: azure-devops

Please forgive me if this has already been asked or if it is just a stupid question.  I am new to trying to setup my own repo and doing configuring.  I am currently working with Microsoft TFS.  I am using the free edition and I have most of it up and going.  My question is, where is the repo being saved to.  I am not using Git.  Before anyone ask, I am not using Git has a starter, my next venture from this is to replicate my findings with Git.  Is the repo being saved local on my machine, or is it in the cloud?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set up TFS, you configured a database. Everything about your TFS instance, including the source code, is stored there.

If you're using VS Team Services (`https://YourProject.visualstudio.com`), it's stored in the cloud.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  It is very appreciated!